# Zero Tensor Product

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, tensor-products, quantum-mechanics

Suppose we have a space $|\psi_1\rangle \otimes |\psi_2\rangle \otimes |\psi_3\rangle$, and operators (matrices) A ⊗ B ⊗ C acting on this Hilbert space (like in quantum mechanics). I'm trying to figure out what A ⊗ B ⊗ C - A ⊗ B ⊗ C is.

By bilinearity, A ⊗ B ⊗ C - A ⊗ B ⊗ C = (A - A) ⊗ B ⊗ C = A ⊗ (B - B) ⊗ C = A ⊗ B ⊗ (C - C) = 0 ⊗ B ⊗ C = A ⊗ 0 ⊗ C = A ⊗ B ⊗ 0. But I'm sure how to conclude that A ⊗ B ⊗ C - A ⊗ B ⊗ C = 0 ⊗ 0 ⊗ 0.

Wolfram Mathworld says x ⊗ 0 = 0 ⊗ y = 0, but I'm not sure what the 0 stands for (does it mean 0 ⊗ 0?).

Any help would be great, and could responses please include references preferably to books that address this specific question? Thanks!

Comment: I changed |$\psi_1$> ⊗ |$\psi_2$> ⊗ |$\psi_3$> to $|\psi_1\rangle \otimes |\psi_2\rangle \otimes |\psi_3\rangle$.  That is standard. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thanks! Btw, what was the latex you used for it?

Comment: \langle and \rangle

Comment: Sweet thanks!!!

Comment: $\ldots$ \langle, \rangle, and \otimes.  You can see what it is be clicking on edit or by right-clicking on the expression itself.  "LaTeX" is a misnomer; this is MathJax. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A key property of tensor *product* is that
$$(\lambda A)\otimes B=A\otimes(\lambda B)$$
for any scalar $\lambda\in\Bbb C$.

Now, apply it for $\lambda=0$, we have
$${\bf0}\otimes B=(0\cdot {\bf0})\otimes B={\bf0}\otimes(0\cdot B)={\bf0}\otimes{\bf0}\,.$$
Similarly for more terms.

Comment: Thanks!! So I'm guessing in this x ⊗ 0 = 0 ⊗ y = 0, the 0 (RHS) is the zero tensor (0 ⊗ 0)?

Comment: Yes, any two tensors which contain a single 0 anywhere will coincide.